# How to fix hover::after and transition within doesn't work?

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

I'm trying to add a cool effect on a button using `::after` and `transition`. But,
it doesn't work as i expected.

I did the following change in scss:

```
    .btn{
       &:link,
       &:visited{
       text-transform: uppercase;
       text-decoration: none;
       padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
       display: inline-block;
       border-radius: 10rem;
       transition: all .2s;
       position: relative;
       font-size: 1.6rem;
      }
      &:hover{
       transform: translateY(-3px);
       box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba($color-black,.2);
        &::after{
          transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
          opacity: 0;
       } }
     &::after{
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 10rem;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      transition: all .4s;
     }
}
```

`&hover` is working as i expected and it gives the proper effect. But, 
`hover::after` isn't working and I can't see my cool effect.Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the effect you are trying to achieve. You need to add a background color to `&::after`

```css
.btn, .btn:link, .btn:visited {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 10rem;
   transition: all .2s;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
.btn:hover{
   transform: translateY(-3px);
   box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem rgba($color-black,.2);
}
.btn:hover:after{
      transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
      opacity: 0;
}
.btn:after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .4s;
 }
```

```html
<a class="btn">Button</a>
```

Comment: actually i added color properties to another ```btn--white``` class and also the i added ```::after``` to it  and set ```background``` color to white                                                                   ```&--white{
  background-color: $color-white;
  color: $color-gray-dark;
  &::after{
    background-color: $color-white;
  }```                                                                                                                                   But,It doesn't work .

Comment: Anyway i expecting the same effect